# C# Null Forgiving Operator Inconsistency

Tags: c#

In using C# 9.0, I've noticed a strange inconsistency:

```
string notNull = "Hello";
string? nullable = null;
notNull = nullable!; // works just fine

Guid notNull = Guid.Empty;
Guid? nullable = null;
// throws a compiler error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'.
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
notNull = nullable!;
notNull = nullable.Value; // works just fine
```

Why is this the case? My understanding is that the null-forgiving operator `!` is identical to wrapping the type in a `Nullable<T>`. I'm not certain why the null-forgiving operator would work in one scenario over the other. `Guid` is a struct type, so I imagine it might have something to do with that. I wasn't able to find anything on this in the C# documentation.

Comment: `My understanding is that the null-forgiving operator ! is identical to wrapping the type in a Nullable<T>.` That is a wrong understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because `string` is a reference (`class`) type, while `Guid` is a value (`struct`) type.  In previous versions of C#, reference types were *always* nullable, so such implicit conversions are tolerated for backwards-compatibility purposes.

For more information, see [Microsoft's documentation on nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Comment: That makes sense. So it seems like to me, reference types may be altered with the ? operator, but this doesn't wrap them in a Nullable<T> because they _can already be null_, from previous versions of C#, whereas a value type, which can't be null, needs to be wrapped in a Nullable<T>. Is this correct?

Comment: @widavies: yes, `Nullable<T>` is `where T : struct`.  It only works for Ts that are structs.  There is no `Nullable<Tref> where Tref : class`